# Fading an object in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm relatively new to as3 and am rewriting a game I have previously written in another language in it. In the intro animation, that leads up to the menu, there is lots of images fading in and out. I know how to make an object transparent using the .alpha, but seem to be struggling to get it to fade back in. I have the image starting off faded out, then I want it to fade in gradually over the course of about .1 of a second, stay there for 4 seconds then fade out.... Thanks.

Comment: You should use `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener to do gradual fading, since this process lasts a certain amount of time. You can also use `Tween` objects to set up various transitions, they use the same technique under the cover. Remember to retain control over any event listeners you create, as you're venturing into an uneven ground that can net you null pointer exceptions (error 1009) with mishandling of either event listeners or frames.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html

Comment: Hi, I think I roughly know how to use enterframe thing, and i know how to use a timer, so that should work, but how long does the enter frame thing last for. I'd need it to last for 20 seconds if I was to make the animation work

Comment: It lasts as long as you don't remove it with `removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ...);` where `...` is you event handler.